# Notation of $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, notation

I have a short question. Would $\mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ represent a Cartesian product of four complex planes? Or, could it represent the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices holding complex numbers? Are both definitions synonymous?

My apologies if the question is obvious. I have never encountered notation with a $\times$ in the exponent for a space.

Thank you all.

Comment: Both definitions are **isomorphic** (not the same) as vector spaces, but usually the $2\times 2$ indicates matrices.

Comment: Could a mapping between them also be made continuously differentiable? Could it be made diffeomorphic as well? Would the notion of a continuously differentiable inverse be well-defined or even useful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\underline{x}\in\Bbb C^4=[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]^T :x_j\in\Bbb C$$
$$\underline{x}\in\Bbb C^{2\times 2}=\bigg[\begin{matrix} x_1 \ x_2 \\x_3 \ x_4\end{matrix}\bigg]:x_j\in\Bbb C$$

Essentially, $\Bbb F^n=\overbrace{\Bbb F\times \cdots \times \Bbb F}^{n\text{ times}}$ represents the cartesian product, while $\Bbb F^{m\times n}$ represents all $\Bbb F$-valued matrices of dimension $m\times n$.

The two work in tandem, indeed, $\Bbb F^{1\times n}=\Bbb F^n$

Answer (score 2):

Given a field $F$ and two natural numbers $m$ and $n$, $F^{m\times n}$ is the set of all $m\times n$ matrices with entries in $F$.

Answer (score 2):

As @JoséCarlosSantos noted, your second guess is right. If we really wanted to multiply the two $2$s to get a $4$, you'd use $\cdot$ instead of $\times$. If the factors were variables with algebraic symbols $m,\,n$, we wouldn't even write $m\cdot n$ because $mn$ is enough.

Comment: If the user had written $\Bbb C_{2\times 2}$ I would have understood faster. +1 to all.